# Fixed Nav Bar/Header Position needs to be changed for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am working on a webpage and I have a fixed header for desktop devices. However, I need to change this for mobile so that the header is not fixed when scrolling. I tried to write a media query but I do not think I did it right.

Here is my code that I had hoped removed the fixed position for mobile devices:

```
header {
  background-color: #2C2D31;
  color: #F0F8FF;
  padding: 25px 10px; /* add padding to left and right */
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); /* add shadow to the header */
  position: fixed; /* make header fixed */
  top: 0; /* position it at the top of the viewport */
  z-index: 1; /* make sure it's on top of other elements */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 390px) {

  header {
  
  position: inherit;
  
  }

  
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use position: static; for header.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 390px) {
  header {
    position: static;
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried static. Header still in the same spot on mobile. Maybe throw the fixed into the nav?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).